# Find a subspace $W$ of $F^4$ such that $F^4=U \oplus W$

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I have to find a subspace $W$ of $F^4$ such that $F^4=U \oplus W$.

$U:=\{(x,x,y,y) \in F^4:x,y \in F\}$

I found the topic with the same problem. The solution was:

$W:=\{(0,b-a,c-d,0)\in F^4:a,b,c,d \in F\}$, because every vector of $F^4$ we can write as:

$(a,b,c,d)=(a,b-a+a,c-d+d,d)=(a,a,d,d)+(0,b-a,c-d,0)$.

I used the similar strategy, but my $W$ is another one. So my solutions is:

$(a,b,c,d)=(a,a,b,b)+(0,b-a,c-b,d-b)$. Therefore I have two questions.

1. Is my $W$ correct?
2. If yes, then subspaces $U$ and $W$ must not be unique? So I can have infinitely many such $W$, which will work for direct sum? Or maybe not infinitely many, but just many?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by $\oplus$.

Comment: @copper.hat direct sum

Comment: It might be easier to write $U$ as the span of $(1,1,0,0), (0,0,1,1)$ from which many possibilities appear. If orthogonality is not required then $W$ is not unique.

Comment: @copper.hat I can't use it, because I will have this topic later.)

Comment: I do not follow, that is essentially how you have expressed $U$ above. $(x,x,y,y) = x(1,1,0,0)+y(0,0,1,1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat ahh. ok. I understand now.

Comment: You will have infinitely many iff your field is infinite. If your field is finite, any finite dimensional vector space over it will be finite. If your field is infinite, then you can argue by various means (for example, using the fact that there's infinitely many inner products) to argue there will be infinitely many complements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you did not state clearly which space your $W$ is, but I will assume that it is$$W=\left\{(0,b−a,c−b,d−b)\mid a,b,c,d\in F\right\}.$$No, this is not right. Take, say, $a=b=0$ and $c=d=1$. Then$$\overbrace{(0,b−a,c−b,d−b)}^{\phantom W\in W}=(0,0,1,1)\in U\setminus\{(0,0,0,0)\},$$and therefore $U\cap W\ne(0,0,0,0)$.

But, yes, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to determine this solutions ( naturally not all, but some of them ) without using span, basis etc?

Comment: Take any two vectors $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that, for any two scalars $\alpha,\beta\in F$, $\alpha w_1+\beta w_2\notin U$ (unless $\alpha=\beta=0$); then take $W=\{\alpha w_1+\beta w_2\mid\alpha,\beta\in F\}$. If you take $w_1=(0,1,0,0)$ and $w_2=(0,0,1,0)$, then you well get that same $W$ as in the given solution.

Comment: I think I got it. For example $w_1=(1,0,0,0)$ and $w_2=(0,0,1,0)$ or $v_1=(1,0,0,0)$ and $v_2=(0,0,0,1)$ will also work, right?

Comment: Yes, they will.